# Can Marketing Cloud In-App Messages be exposed in non-mobile web experiences?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilestudio

I understand that In-App Messaging helps deliver messages to iOS and Android devices...but can it also deliver and display messages for traditional browser experiences?  Is it intended for those use cases, or is it only recommended for Mobile apps?

Also, once the message is rendered, can the user see the message in all of their devices, or does it get pushed and persisted locally on a particular device.

I'm trying to determine whether this feature will allow us to deliver once, but have a user see the message across all our channels.

Comment: I would reach out to your Sales Support Engineers to answer these questions.